# CSS Last Odd Child?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have an unordered list, which can contain either an even or odd number of items. I'm looking for a CSS-only way to remove the border from the last 2 `li` tags if the number of `li`s is even. The `:last-child` pseudo-selector removes the last one regardless.

```
li {
float: left;
border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
}

li:last-child{
border-bottom: none;
}
```

#### Works for Odd Numbers of `li`s

```
+============================================+
+          1          |          2           +
+--------------------------------------------+
+          3          |                      +
+============================================+
```

#### But for even numbers, I need to remove the bottom of cell #3

```
+============================================+
+          1          |          2           +
+--------------------------------------------+
+          3          |          4           +
+---------------------                       +
+============================================+
```

So I figured I could use `li:nth-last-child()` but I can't figure out what should be the equation to grab the last odd child.

It's not `2n+1`, `2n-1`, `n-1`, or anything I can think of. Please help.

Answer (score 110, accepted):

nth-last-child counts backwards from the last child, so to grab the second to last, the expression is:

```
li:nth-last-child(2)
```

You can combine pseudo-selectors, so to select the 2nd to last child, but only when it's odd, use:

```
li:nth-last-child(2):nth-child(odd) {border-bottom: none;}
```

And so, the whole thing should be:

```
li:last-child,
li:nth-last-child(2):nth-child(odd) {border-bottom: none;}
```

In answer to @ithil's question, here's how I'd write it in SASS:

```
li
  &:last-child,
  &:nth-last-child(2):nth-child(odd)
    border-bottom: none
```

It's not that much simpler, since the selection of the 'second-to-last odd child' is always going to require the 'two step' selector.

In answer to @Caspert's question, you can do this for arbitrarily many last elements by grouping more selectors (there feels like there should be some `xn+y` pattern to do this without grouping, but AFAIU these patterns just work by counting backwards from the last element).

For three last elements:

```
li:last-child,
li:nth-last-child(2):nth-child(odd),
li:nth-last-child(3):nth-child(odd) {border-bottom: none;}
```

This is a place where something like SASS can help, to generate the selectors for you. I would structure this as a placeholder class, and extend the element with it, and set the number of columns in a variable like this:

```
$number-of-columns: 3

%no-border-on-last-row
 @for $i from 1 through $number-of-columns
   &:nth-last-child($i):nth-child(odd)
     border-bottom: none

//Then, to use it in your layout, just extend:

.column-grid-list li
  @extend %no-border-on-last-row
```

Comment: @fskreuz: That's probably a few years out of date. Consider finding a more up-to-date reference.

Comment: it has 'LAST UPDATED THU 15 DEC 2011 06:20:47 AM CET' at the bottom of the article. And based on http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp: *The :nth-child() selector is supported in all major browsers, except IE8 and earlier.*

Comment: TIL pseudo-selectors can be combined like regular selectors... I knew there was something I was conceptually missing, but wasn't sure what it was. Thanks!

Comment: any idea if this solution could it be "simplified" by using a preprocessor such as sass/less?

Comment: I've added the equivalent in SASS to the answer. I haven't used LESS in a while - not sure how it would look in it, or whether it'd be any simpler.

Comment: @Beejamin I'm looking for the same thing, but then for the last 3 items (3 columns grid)... Is this possible?

Comment: Sure, @Caspert - I've added a method to the answer.

Answer (score 17):

Another alternative:

```
li:last-child:not(:nth-child(odd))
```

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/W72nR/

Comment: Reference: http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#last-child-pseudo, http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#nth-child-pseudo

Comment: Simple and exactly what I was looking for, thanks.

Comment: Simple and elegant! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

This works for me. Dynamically select the last odd child.

```
li:nth-last-child(1):nth-child(odd)
```

Answer (score 1):

possibly:

```
li:nth-child(2n){border:1px dashed hotpink}
li:nth-child(2n-2), li:last-child{border:none;}
```

Comment: 2n will select every other `li`, starting from the 2nd, and 2n-2 will select every 2nd child, starting from the 0th. However, CSS counts from 1 (not 0), so these two selectors will effectively select the same elements. This doesn't solve the problem in the question.

Answer (score -5):

you can use the nth child selector:

```
li:nth-child(3) { border-bottom: none;}

li:nth-child(4) {border-bottom: none;}
```

However since this is not supported in IE 8... you should just set a class to those two li elements and use specificity to set the border-bottom to none.

Comment: This will only ever grab the 3rd or 4th child - it won't work with an arbitrary number of items.

Comment: This does not do what the OP is asking for.