# How to select only items in the last row?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, css-selectors

I was wondering how I can select the last items in a row. I know the nth selector is to select the last items, for example the last 3 items in a row:

```
.post-entry:nth-last-child(-n+3) { margin-bottom: 0; }
```

But this doesn't meet my needs. It works great if there are 3 items at the end of the last row, but when there are just 2 last posts, it isn't working.

When you delete one item in the above example, the layout is messed up:

[image]

What I would like to know is how to select the last item(s) in the last row without messing up my layout like the image above. Also, if there are only two or maybe one items left.

```css
.post {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  border-bottom: 3px solid red;
}
.post img {
  width: 100%;
}
.post:nth-last-child(-n+3) {
  margin-bottom: 0;
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  
  <div class="col-md-4 post"><img src="http://placehold.it/300x200"></div>
  <div class="col-md-4 post"><img src="http://placehold.it/300x200"></div>
  <div class="col-md-4 post"><img src="http://placehold.it/300x200"></div>

  <div class="col-md-4 post"><img src="http://placehold.it/300x200"></div>
  <div class="col-md-4 post"><img src="http://placehold.it/300x200"></div>
  <div class="col-md-4 post"><img src="http://placehold.it/300x200"></div>

  <div class="col-md-4 post"><img src="http://placehold.it/300x200"></div>
  <div class="col-md-4 post"><img src="http://placehold.it/300x200"></div>
  <div class="col-md-4 post"><img src="http://placehold.it/300x200"></div>

</div>
```

Here is my Codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/aZpqbK

Comment: This works for me. What browser are you using

Comment: What do you mean *"So how can I select the last items in a row?"* how many *items* from the last you want to select?

Comment: Updated my answer. @TJ, I mean how I can select the last items in the last row. With the nth selector `-n+3` is this possible, but when the row doesn't contain 3 items, for example only 2 items, it will meshed up my layout.

Comment: @Caspert I don't see any *answer* posted by you. You are using the term *last items* which doesn't make sense. What is *last items* in a container? Everything expect the first?

Comment: @TJ Apologize, I mean my question instead of answer. I would like to select the last items in a row, the last row. To be more precise, if I have 6 items, I want to be able to select the 4th, 5th and 6th of items. If there are 7 items, I want to select only the 7th item. If there are 8, select the 7th and 8th item. In short: only select the items in the last row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hard to set css as required using nth-child in you case. I think, it is not possible only with CSS.

I have try with overlay pattern. It is not great idea, but it is good in your case. It is simple and work with all responsive layout and ***n*** numbers of items.

**Check Result:
[click me for 9 items](https://fiddle.jshell.net/vkhk53tm/2/show/) and
[click me for 8 items](https://fiddle.jshell.net/vkhk53tm/3/show/)**

**[Click me to check in responsive layout](https://www.responsinator.com/?url=https%3A%2F%2Ffiddle.jshell.net%2Fvkhk53tm%2F2%2Fshow%2F)**

```css
.container{    position: relative;}
.post { 
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  border-bottom: 3px solid red;
}
.post img { width:100%; }

#overlay-div{
    background-color: white;
    height: 40px;
    width: 100%;
    bottom: 0;
    position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="col-md-4 post"><img src="http://placehold.it/300x200"></div>
  <div class="col-md-4 post"><img src="http://placehold.it/300x200"></div>
  <div class="col-md-4 post"><img src="http://placehold.it/300x200"></div>

  <div class="col-md-4 post"><img src="http://placehold.it/300x200"></div>
  <div class="col-md-4 post"><img src="http://placehold.it/300x200"></div>
  <div class="col-md-4 post"><img src="http://placehold.it/300x200"></div>

  <div class="col-md-4 post"><img src="http://placehold.it/300x200"></div>
  <div class="col-md-4 post"><img src="http://placehold.it/300x200"></div>
  <div class="col-md-4 post"><img src="http://placehold.it/300x200"></div>

  <div id="overlay-div"></div> <!-- this div hide last line of border -->
</div>
```

[EDIT]

**I found another way,**

http://keithclark.co.uk/articles/targeting-first-and-last-rows-in-css-grid-layouts/

**Demo** : [codepen.io](http://codepen.io/keithclark/full/Hygkt)

Comment: Thank you. I was searching on the web and came to this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8641003/css-last-odd-child Maybe it is still possible with css-only... What do you think?

Comment: Yes, but it (odd/even) will work for two columns only. above solution will work with **n** numbers of column. ;)

Comment: @Caspert, Finally, i found solution with CSS only. See my edit section.