# jQuery: selecting the last div only when it is odd

Tags: jquery, html, forms

I am trying to style a landing page with a two column form that has a varying number of fields. The page will sometimes use a form with an even number of fields and sometimes use a form with an odd number of fields. I would like to have the last field of the form to display full width rather than 2 columns when it has an odd number of fields.

I'm thinking this would require some jquery but I'm not too sure how to do that.

Each input field of the form is wrapped by a div with the class="row".
I would like the "row" class to be width:100% for the last field if there are an odd number of form fields.

UPDATE:

Below is an example of the structure of my form. I also have two fields at the bottom that have an additional class (floatDIV) added to it using jquery when the form loads but I only want the text / email / tel / select fields to be counted in as the number of fields used to determine odd/even. I also can't remove any existing classes.

I can't really find a way to use last-child or nth-child since I'm trying to target the class.

```html
<form>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <input id="name" name="name" type="text" class="field" placeholder="name">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <input id="email" name="email" type="email" class="field" placeholder="email">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <input id="phone" name="phone" type="tel" class="field" placeholder="phone">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <input id="phone" name="phone" type="tel" class="field" placeholder="phone">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row floatDIV">
    <div class="col">
      <div><span>some text</span></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row floatDIV">
    <div class="col">
      <label for="content" class="label"><span>some text</span></label>
      <div class="checkbox">
        <input name="checkbox" id="checkbox" type="checkbox" value="yes" class="field">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="button">
    <button type="submit" class="btn">Submit</button>
  </div>
  <input type="hidden" name="formid" class="field" value="4">
  <input type="hidden" name="pageid" class="field" value="5">
</form>
```

What I currently have selects the last odd div even if the form has an even number of fields which is not what I want. I would like it to only add the new style to the very last row that doesn't have the floatDIV class only if it is an odd field.

```js
$('.row:odd').not(".floatDIV").last().addClass('last');
```

Comment: Please show us an example of the markup you are wanting to manipulate, at a minimum.

Comment: `.row:nth-child(odd):last-child` will be enough

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS Last Odd Child?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8641003/css-last-odd-child)

Answer (score 0):

I think this is something like you are looking for:

```js
var evenodd;

if (Math.floor($('.row').length / 2) === ($('.row').length / 2)) {
  console.log('even');
} else {
  console.log('odd');
  $('.columns').addClass('odd');
}
```

```css
.columns{
  box-sizing:border-box;
}

.row {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 48%;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.columns.odd .row:last-child {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="columns">

  <div class="row">
    A
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    B
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    C
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    D
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    E
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: As I said in my comment above `.row:nth-child(odd):last-child` instead of `.columns.odd .row:last-child` will do the job .. with no need to use javascript code at all

Comment: I think that is true only when he has an odd number of items.  He states it could be odd or even.

Comment: Just tested and you are 100% correct.  Thanks for teaching me something!

Comment: NVM .. We all still learning ;) .. Have a great day :-) @Jennifer